# If one of the spatial directions wrapped around, how would combat be different?

Tags: warfare, combat, alien-geometry

This is a test drive of the [alien-geometry](/questions/tagged/alien-geometry). I hope it will be a fun tag.

Okay, for the purposes of this question, the world is flat (like, you still have plants and hills and stuff, just no long term curvature.) We don't care how far it goes, or why it like that.

So we have a world much like ours. We have sunlight during the day and moonlight at night. Plants and animals and such. The only difference is if you move 5 feet to East or West, you end up in the same place.

To visualize this, every object is visually repeated infinitely to the East and West every 5 feet. Of course, these are all the same object (they won't diverge or anything). You only viewing it from different angles. You can imagine sort of that the entire world is like a cylinder with a circumference of 5 feet (except that it isn't curved and the ground is still really deep.)

If we want to be precise, an infinity by infinity by 5 feet space, and [topologically glue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)#Examples) the two faces of this space together.

I hope to ask a lot of questions about this world, but to start off, let's look at combat.

- If I have something in my right hand, and I can put it into my left hand.
- I can arrange myself so the enemy is both directly to my right and left.
- I can fire projectiles far to the left or right (wrapping around the East-West dimension a couple times) to hit my opponent in the side.

How will combat be different? Both 1 on 1, and smallish battles (not thinking about big battles or wars yet.)

Comment: [Standard Not-the-downvoter disclaimer] So you're not on a planet, but a five-by-infinity flat plane? That raises some tough questions, such as "How can *anything* survive?"

Comment: @HDE226868 There's still ground and sun light and such.

Comment: My only issue is that such a setup is just . . . in want of handwavium. I suppose I'm being nit-picky though, so don't mind me.

Comment: @HDE226868 I haven't fleshed it out yet.

Answer (score 14):

Its similar to fighting in a 5ft wide corridor of infinite length.

A defensive fighter would want to face opponent on a north south axis along the corridor.  A large shield or two men standing abreast you block the entire world from getting past.  Two attackers could charge forward with spears knowing their foes could never side step around them.

In a skirmish the vast majority of troops would be archers lobbing attacks over the handful of melee troops

It would seem that only a few dozen troops could participate in a war.  The narrow confines also remove the traditional attackers advantage of choosing the site of battle, you don't need to defend a whole castle only 5ft of wall.  Defense becomes much more effective.

Answer (score 9):

1 on 1, you are in a world of complexity. Martial artists have an infinite edge over non-martial artists as they can appear to kick on the right side and hit the opponent on the left! Also there are very high chances a short range projectile weapon (like a slingshot) would be used by every combatant. The most shocking battles would ensue when the opponents face each other in east-west direction. Now you they not only have to defend themselves from the front, but the back too, as both parties can strike behind their backs and it will hit the opponent in their backs.

Generally in this world weapons like the [Meteor Hammer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteor_hammer) and the [Rope Dart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rope_dart) would have far higher effectiveness against fixed-shape weapons like the sword, spear, mace etc. Battles where two masters fight, one with a fix-shape weapon (sword) and the other with a rope-dart would be immensely complex, both to write and to comprehend.

In battles involving projectiles, every trooper would be trained rigorously about how to hit the opponent on both sides while standing right in front of him at much distance.

Detailed analysis of weapons and combat tactics depends on what level of technology the residents of this universe have, as compared to ours.

Comment: "Martial artists have an infinite edge over non-martial artists as they can appear to kick on the right side and hit the opponent on the left!" - I disagree. You see opponents near you to the left and to the right and you see which one is about to hit you. It is more like fighting in a line, only that all your opponents do exactly the same and all your friends (including you) do exactly the same. I still agree with the later part of the first paragraph.

Comment: Opponents are facing each other in north-south direction. The martial artist runs to the right (east) side of his opponent and delivers a jumping/flying kick at the edge of the dimension. The martial artist will disappear on the east and reappear mid-kick in the west and land the kick on the ***left*** side of his opponent while he was preparing to defend it on the right side. How does that sound?

Comment: "To visualize this, every object is visually repeated infinitely to the East and West every 5 feet. Of course, these are all the same object" So the martial artist does not disappear and reappear. On the other side, yes, the opponent sees that copies of the martial artist are about to kick to the east and has a problem: will the copy that is facing him kick him from the east or the copy that is west of him kick him.

Comment: Doesn't that really give a huge edge to the martial artist over a non martial artist? Now instead of having to face and stop one kick, he has to face and stop 2  !!

Comment: You can split kick people on both sides of the head at the same time.

Comment: Yes that too! @PyRulez

Answer (score 2):

Would a being evolved in such a space really even perceive the duplicate images, or would their wetware evolve to eliminate the cognitive overload of the redundancy? Perhaps they would only perceive a single instance of each object, albeit viewed simultaneously from many angles. Perhaps their perceptions would convert the flat space around them into a perceived cylinder, to give them awareness of the wraparound effects?

Comment: I've even thought about creatures evolving around the east west direction. (The west side is connected to the east side.) A solid wall tree could be annoying.