# If one of the spatial dimensions *not* perpendicular to gravity wrapped around, how would architecture be different?

Tags: architecture, alien-geometry

Continuing [this question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/27821/if-one-of-the-spatial-dimensions-wrapped-around-how-would-architecture-be-diffe), but with a slight change. In this world, if you go 7 feet east, and then 7 feet *up*, you would be in the same place. Note that the ground wouldn't be perpendicular to gravity. It would have to be sloped for this to work.

My question is, how would this affect architecture? One thing to note is that although the ground is naturally sloped, you could cut steps into it to make travelling easier (although creatures may not be used to levelness). Additionally, if you made two story house (each story being 7 feet), and went 7 feet west of the first floor, the first floor would be 7 feet below you; you would be on the second floor. How this is connected would have to be addressed.

How big could buildings be made? How would buildings be renovated and made bigger? How would architecture be different?

Note: For the purposes of this question, there is a uniform downward gravitational field of 1G (if you prefer, you may think of it as if there was no gravity, but the entire world was accelerating upward with 1G of acceleration.)

Note: This is different from the linked question because in that question, the wrapped around dimension and gravity where at a 90 degree angle. In this, it is at a 45 degree angle.

Comment: All you really did was change the question by 90 degrees...

Comment: @bowlturner And all the novel orthongonal changed was a sign in the spacetime signature.

Comment: @PyRulez Nothing's changed. It's akin to rotating the world by 45 degrees and extending the distance needed to come back to where you started (from $7$ feet to $7\sqrt{2}$ feet).

Comment: @HDE226868 Rotating 45 degrees is huge! Perpetual motion, for example, is now possible.

Comment: @PyRulez It's just a change in coordinate system. It also wouldn't be possible to create perpetual motion, either, because it would still violate the laws of thermodynamics.

Comment: @HDE226868 Since the ground is sloped, a wheel would roll forever. If you look at it as a change in coordinate system, its also a change to gravity.

Comment: @PyRulez It wouldn't. The gravitational potential of an object would simply have a minimum at the maximum distance away from the object.

Comment: @HDE226868 When you go west and down, you can gain kinetic energy. But you're in the same place, so you can do it again.

Comment: @PyRulez Think of a circle, and imagine that for an object constrained to move on the boundary of that circle, the potential energy is based on distance. There is a minimum potential energy, and the object will tend toward that point. **It can not gain energy forever, because it will not go back to its original point and keep accelerating.** It will tend toward the extremum of the potential.

Comment: @HDE226868 gravity works in the down direction. Its like a circle where gravity acts clockwise.

Comment: @PyRulez Why not in the up direction? If this universe is closed, the same should happen. You can't treat the universe like it's on the surface of Earth. There's no preferred direction in the universe.